# How do I fix this issue with my sort of RLE program

Tags: java

This is a (kind of) RLE I'm working on for school

I don't really understand how every time I execute the program it keeps printing out that A had a count of 5 when there's actually 4 A's there, and how can I solve this

```
         String x = "AAAARRRGGH" + " "; 
         int z = 0;
         int count = 0;
         Boolean condition = false;
         
        while(condition == false) {
            
            for(int i = 0; i<x.length(); i++) {
                count++;
                if(x.charAt(i) != x.charAt(z)) {
                    System.out.println("" + x.charAt(z) + count);
                    z = i;
                    count = 0;
                     if(x.charAt(z) == x.charAt(x.length()-1)) {
                        condition = true;
                     }
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide *x* whenever the character changes.

```java
String x = "AAAARRRGGH" + " ";
List<String> ss = new ArrayList<>();
int z = 0;
for (int i = 1, n = x.length(); i < n; i++)
    if (x.charAt(i - 1) != x.charAt(i))
        ss.add(x.substring(z, z = i));
ss.add(x.substring(z));
```

Then, generate a *String* for each *ss* element.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
int n;
for (String e : ss) {
    s.append(e.charAt(0));
    if ((n = e.length()) != 1) s.append(n);
}
```

Output

```
A4R3G2H
```